# Unintuitive performance when searching for missing number in stream

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

**Overview:**

- Learning C++
- Practicing on [GeeksforGeeks - "Missing number in
  array"](http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/missing-number-in-array/0)
- Aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798968/performance-when-searching-for-missing-numbers-in-array)(Java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475795/check-for-missing-number-in-sequence)(C#), but the answers aren't sufficient for my question

**Challenge:**

- Fed integers in a random order from 1 to N
- One is missing - print it
- T is the number of test cases
- N <= 1000
- C contains all the numbers but the missing number

**Input Stream Format:**
T
N1
C1
N2
C2
...

**Sample Input:**
2
5
1 2 3 5
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10

**Sample Output:**
4
9

**My Question:**

- **std::array** implementation is nearly twice as fast as subtracting the the feed from **(N*(N+1))/2**
- I get asymptotic time complexity is O(n) for both
- However, I'm surprised by the difference, why isn't the math trick faster, let alone a multiple slower?
- Feel free to critique both my implementation and style.

Method 1 with **std::array**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using std::array;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    array<unsigned, 1000> inputs;

    unsigned numTests;
    cin >> numTests;
    while (numTests--)
    {
        unsigned lenCount;
        cin >> lenCount;
        unsigned lenArray(lenCount);
        while (--lenCount)
        {
            unsigned input;
            cin >> input;
            inputs[input - 1] = 1;
        }

        for (unsigned index = 0; index != lenArray; ++index)
        {
            if (inputs[index] == 0)
            {
                cout << index + 1 << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        inputs.fill(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Method 2 with math trick:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    unsigned numTests;
    cin >> numTests;
    while (numTests--)
    {
        unsigned lenArray;
        cin >> lenArray;
        unsigned answer = (lenArray*(lenArray+1))/2;
        while (--lenArray)
        {
            unsigned input;
            cin >> input;
            answer -= input;
        }

        cout << answer << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the array method actually working given this bug (should be lencount)?
for (unsigned index = 0; index != lenArray; ++index)

Comment: @DaveS It shouldn't be `lencount` since `lencount` is zero by that point.

Comment: How are you measuring their run time, and what input are you using?

Comment: > "@DaveS It shouldn't be lencount since lencount is zero by that point"

You're right, but lenArray is the array itself, so  lenArray.size() then.

Comment: @DaveS No, the entire array may not be filled. `cin >> lenCount;` sets the number of array elements that are actually used, then `lenArray` is populated with this value. It's like having a vector with capacity=1000 but size=50, for example.

Comment: OP: You are missing `inputs.fill(0);` after declaring `inputs`. The array contents are default-initialized, which does not initialize non-class elements. So the first sample doesn't even do what you want.

Comment: The values are filled with cin, so there is no need to initialize them. lenArray ensures I only work with those that have been filled, so I don't worry about the uninitialized values for the first run through. Then when I don't want 1's lingering, I fill the thing with zeros. Would it be faster to just create a new array? Anyway, the first program ran fine both on my machine, and on GeeksforGeeks. I'll provide the input details above, but they are in the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before going into my results you have an error in your first program: you are missing `inputs.fill(0);` immediately after declaring `inputs` -- the contents of the array are default-initialized, which means no initialization is performed since `unsigned` is not a class type.

---

I took the (fixed) first program, the second program, and a third program I wrote and ran them against 10,000 tests of 1,000 numbers each.  What I found was that all three programs consistently took about two seconds to run, within the margin of error.  That is to say, they perform equivalently with this particular set of input.

All samples were compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -pedantic`. The output of `g++ --version`: `g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2`

The third program was this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned t;
    while (std::cin >> t);
    return 0;
}
```

Surprised?

The lesson here is that formatted I/O is slow.  *Really slow.*

Even though the array algorithm should theoretically be at least three times as slow as the math-based algorithm (there are 2500 average loop iterations per trial instead of 1000 with the math-based algorithm), the overhead of formatted I/O is so high that the difference in the efficiency of the two algorithms for such a small list of numbers is insignificant by comparison.

It's like having three bathtubs nearly full of water (the same amount in each) and adding three drops to one of the tubs, one drop to the second, and adding nothing to the third, and wondering why the water levels are still pretty much the same.  The initial fill of water represents the overhead of formatted I/O and the added drops represent the time the actual algorithm is running.

An aside: this is the reason we tell people not to prematurely optimize.  What you often think is the bottleneck is, in fact, many orders of magnitude faster than where the actual bottleneck will almost always be: waiting for some kind of I/O (usually disk or network).  That's not to say you shouldn't optimize, but generally you should optimize *after* benchmarking as the hot path is rarely where you think it will be.

(I can't explain why the array-based algorithm would be significantly faster in your tests; my trials did not demonstrate this at all.  In the absence of access to the test machine, benchmark methodology, or any explanation for the discrepancy, I am inclined to disregard those results as flawed.)

Comment: Wow. Why is it so slow?

Comment: IO in general is slow (syscalls and context switches are involved), and C++ iostream add a lot of overhead, especially for formatted input.